# Estilo CSS no me funciona en Chrome

Tags: css

Amigos, tengo un estilo que no me funciona en Chrome, pero sí en Firefox. Es un estilo para agrandar un poco más el option de un select y lo aplico directamente al elemento option. Les dejo el estilo:

```
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
          <label for="selTorneo">Seleccione Torneo:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="selTorneo">
          </select>
        </div>


option
{
    height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

*Si existe una mejor manera de hacer esto, quedo atento*

Comment: Prueba poniendo esto a la hora de vincular tu CSS: `src="/css/styles.css?v=aqui_un_numero_aleatorio"`. Hay veces que Chrome no recarga bien el CSS. Puede ser problema de eso

Comment: Hola @cnbandicoot , puse esto <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/css_programacion.css?v=2"> pero no funcionó. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que la etiqueta option no se le pueden asignar estilos, te dejo una respuesta del foro en inglés donde lo explican:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit

De todas formas, si en lugar de asignar a option esos estilos, se los asignas directamente al select, si que te funciona, te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<style type="text/css">
    select {
        height: 40px;
        max-height: 40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="selTorneo">Seleccione Torneo:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selTorneo">
        <option value="1">Ejemplo</value>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: No me funcionó con el select en ambos navegadores. Gracis por la información del option.

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente dar `padding` ni `heigth` a un `<option>` en chrome no es posible

> **padding**
>   Setting padding on an optgroup or option has no effect in Chrome so you cannot control the amount of indentation. You can set the padding of a select as a whole in Chrome (as you can with IE8) but it looks really weird. Unlike IE8 you can click anywhere in the select to open it even if it has padding.

```css
.selector option{
    font-size : 20px;
    background-color : red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label for="selTorneo">Seleccione Torneo:</label>
  <select class="form-control selector" id="selTorneo">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, no esperaba que no se pudiera hacer algo así. Buscaré una alternativa.

Comment: Perfecto, puedes ocupar frameworks de style como bootstrap que combinan librerias jquery para tu ayuda!. Si te ayudo mi respuesta recuerda marcarla :) saludos!