# Dar estilo a option de un select

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentado darle estilos a las opciones del Select. He intentado varias cosas pero lo único que he logrado es darle color, mas no altura, separadores de color blanco y demás.

Dejo el código:

```css
.cmbColumn {
  background: #2f3640;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-boton: 8px;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.cmbColumn .option {
  height: 30px;
  border-button: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">Multi Label Search</h2>
<div class="widget-content">
  <div id="multi-search">
    <select id="cmbColumn" class="cmbColumn" name="cmbcolumn">
      <option value="" />Columns
      <option value="1%20Column+" />1 Column
      <option value="2%20Column+" />2 Column
      <option value="3%20Column+" />3 Column
      <option value="4%20Column+" />4 Column
    </select>
    <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Lograr esto es lo que busco, Si es posible con una linea separadora entre options de color blanco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas tratado por favor

Comment: Disculpe, Olvide agregarlo. Esta hecho.

Comment: @RicharlyxD agrega como querrías que quedara, con un dibujo o algo similar

Comment: Entiendo, Lo acabo de agregar

Comment: No se puede hacer (al menos no tal y como está en la imagen). Los estilos de los option son específicos a cada navegador y como mucho podrás actualizar los colores (y en algunos navegadores ni eso). La imagen muestra unos option con fuente, color, fondo, espaciado, etc. diferente. Para hacer eso debes simular un select usando divs.

Comment: Ésta es una pregunta que se ha realizado ya antes (algunos ejemplos  [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/151164/250), [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110578/250), o [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73154/250)) y la respuesta siempre es parecida.

Comment: Entiendo, Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Cualquier cambio en los estilos del select que puede no verse igual en todos los navegadores y aún así las opciones son limitadas, pero una manera de hacerlo es usar un div que al clickarlo despliegue una lista con JavaScript y cada "li" sea una de las opciones, simulando un select. Luego, cada vez que elijas una opción, su valor debe guardarse en donde debería ir el valor del select.

En las respuestas a está pregunta puedes ver un ejemplo de código para hacerlo: [¿Como cambiar los estilos css de las opciones de un select?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74376/como-cambiar-los-estilos-css-de-las-opciones-de-un-select)

Igualmente, como contra, hay que tener en cuenta que usar etiquetas que no corresponden puede dificultar la accesibilidad.

Comment: Siempre es mejor añadir un ejemplo con tu respuesta.